Cabin altitude display on pressurized aircraft; why not display baro corrected cabin altitude?
Pressurized aircraft displays Cabin alt, differential pressure, and cabin climb rate.
It appears to me that the cabin altitude is displayed as non-baro corrected cabin altitude (pressure altitude of the cabin).
My question is what is reason or logic behind choosing to display it as pressure altitude of the cabin as opposed to baro corrected altitude of the cabin?
I'm pretty sure the controller schedules cabin pressure such that cabin pressure is equivalent to baro corrected field elevation upon landing. This would match baro corrected cabin altitude upon landing but based on my experience in my aircraft, the cabin alt display is often several hundred feet different from my PFD's displayed altitude at landing while diff P is zero point zero. If I set my PFD baro to 29.92 after landing, the cabin alt display then matches the PFD's displayed altitude.
Is displaying pressure altitude of the cabin as opposed to baro corrected cabin altitude some industry standard or requirement? Seems non optimal.

I'm not sure what benefit you'd gain from baro corrected altitude. The question we're trying to answer is "can the passengers breathe or not?" which only considers the raw pressure altitude of the cabin.

When the aircraft is above the transition altitude and is flying across the country, with the pilots unconcerned about what the local altimeter setting is miles below them (since they're level at FL whatever), what would be the appropriate setting to give the pressure controller?  Cabin pressurization is all about human physiology, not terrain clearance, and human physiology doesn't care what local pressure is, but rather the atmospheric pressure "here". Or, really, the partial pressure of O2 in the lungs. Which needs no baro correction to know exactly.
